# How to convert string , date, time, byte into bitarray in C#

Tags: c#, byte, bitarray

I am trying to get the functions for converting string to bitarray, 
date to bitarray
time to bitarray
byte to bit array. 
Can anyone please help me with these functions in c#.

Comment: Please update your post with sample of what you are trying to achieve (i.e. "foo" should be converted to XXXXX) and what you tried/have problem with. Otherwise too broad for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness, I'll include my method for turning arbitrary objects to byte arrays (it's probably faster than a BinaryFormatter and MemoryStream):

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(object obj)
{
    int len = Marshal.SizeOf(obj);
    byte[] arr = new byte[len];
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(len);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, true);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, len);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get built into the framework is the [`System.BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class and the [`System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes.aspx) method. Beyond this, you'll need code to [convert those byte arrays into bit arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xda43a.aspx) (though, really, for any sane operation a byte array is better) and none of these cover date/time information (you might look at converting a DateTime's `Ticks` property instead).

Comment: +1 for `DateTime.Ticks`.  It's probably the only sensible way to move date information around in a binary format (other than the actual DateTime object, of course).

Answer (score 1):

If you consider any type as an object you can use a general method to obtain a `byte[]`

```
private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object myObject)

{
    if(myObject == null)
        return null;
    BinaryFormatter bF = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream mS = new MemoryStream();
    bF.Serialize(mS, myObject);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Then you can feed it to the constructor of [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xda43a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)